# python Selenium close popup HTTP authentication

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to create small python script, all working fine but have one problem that need to close popup HTTP authentication.

[image]

how can close this ? I have tried with :

```
driver.common.keys.Keys.ESCAPE
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Did you add this ? from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try by passing proxy user name & password in the URL that you are trying to access.

```
driver.get("http://username:password@www.yourAppURL.com/")
```

Comment: @kingcope That's strange, because with that URL no popup should come up at all.

Comment: @watery if the password is wrong the popup is open .. and blocked the script !

Answer (score 0):

if you dont need authorization you could just pass it by closing allert

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert() 
alert.dismiss()
```